# Strategy for "Lights Out" game

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Sorry but I didn’t find a better title.

I have a question. 
Imagine a square divided into four equal squares: A, B, C and D. Each of these squares is equipped with a state function such that A, B, C, D are equal to either 1 or 0. 
Consider the initial situation: A = 1 and B, C, D = 0. 
If I choose A then the neighboring squares of A change their state and A also. 
In this example A = 0 B = 1 and C = 1 and D = 0 since it does not touch A. 
I'm looking for a way to get all squares equal to 1. And more generally if for example it's any shape such as for example a T-shaped pattern that is broken down into squares equal to a T. Which steps would be needed to obtain all squares equal to 1 or a method permitting to say whether there is a solution or not without necessarily finding the solution.

In fact it’s like the game “Lights Out”

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: If I understand the rules of your problem, when the game is in the state A=1, B,C,D=0, would choosing D make your square all 1?

Comment: This sounds like [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)).

Comment: Yes it’s like Lights Out

Comment: It's nothing but a system of linear equations over $\mathbb F_2$.